Python setyp.py entrypoint referencing
I have a setup.py for my python project for wheel packaging and have defined entrypoints as given below:
entry_points={
        "group_1": [
            "entrypoint_1=src.jobs.execution.loader_1:main",
            "entrypoint_2=src.jobs.execution.mapper:main",
        ],
        "group_2": [
            "entrypoint_1=src.jobs.jobs.execution.loader_2:main",
            "entrypoint_2=src.jobs.execution.mapper_2:main",
        ],}

For logical reasons, the entrypoints are under different group and I wanted to use the same entrypoint name under different groups. Is something like above possible where I use the same entrypoint name a number of times under different groups or all the entrypoints need to be unique? How would I refer to these in a program run if it is possible?
